# regex for special character

Tags: jquery, regex

In Jquery i want a function which should not allow special character.
I want some thing like this:

```
function CheckFileName(Name) {
            $('span.error-keyup-2').remove();
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
            if (!characterReg.test(Name)) {
                $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-2">No special characters allowed.</span>');
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I know its not work.there is not any thing like `test`.But unable to use `regex pattern` in `jquery`.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [test()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method of a regular expression object so your code will work. `pattern.test(string)` returns true if string matches given pattern.