# regex for filename

Tags: jquery, regex, expression, filenames

i continue with this question.Its help and work.[regex for special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293078/regex-for-special-character/9293262#9293262).My regex pattern is:

```
var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
```

it accept`a-zA-z0-9` only.But i want a regex which also support underscore(_) and das(-).I am unable to modify regex pattern because it is out of my mind.Plz some one suggest a correct pattern for my situation.

Comment: It does not related to jquery at all :) `a-zA-z0-9` and `,` and space. `which also support underscore(_) and das(-)` try `/^\s*[a-z-_\d,\s]+\s*$/i`

Comment: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is a pretty good tool to use for any regex writing/testing. just fyi. greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_,\s-]+\s*$/;`
`-` is a special character and means range if you write it between two chars. So you can escape it (`\\-`) or just put in the end of `[]`'s content.
Actually you can write `\\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_`.`\\w` is a word character (letters, digits, and underscores).
And also `\s*` in the end is unnecessary because there is a whitespace in your square braces and `[\\w,\s-]+` will match this `foo bar-123` wholly
I think this is better: `var characterReg = /^\s*[\\w,\s-]+$/;`